# How can I change the font face for source code blocks in org-mode?

Tags: org-mode, themes

I tried to change both `org-code` and `org-verbatim` without success. Here is the relevant part of my theme:

```
'(org-verbatim ((nil (:inherit 'fixed-pitch))))
'(org-code ((nil (:inherit 'fixed-pitch))))
```

The setting for checkboxes does get applied however `'(org-checkbox ((nil (:inherit 'fixed-pitch))))`.